@PlanningPin with Chained Planning Variable
In Timefold, how to deal with pinning an entity when its a chained planning variable?
I have WorkOrder PlanningEntity that's a chained planning variable that is assigned to a technician. If I pinned a workorder (so the startime and assigned tech is fixed), it gets pinned correctly but the solver no longer add any workorder to this technician. How do I adjust it so that solver solves around the pinned work orders? (add work order before/after the pinned work order)
Added @PlanningPin to the WorkOrder class
@PlanningPin
private boolean pinned;


I am not aware of a support for a more fine-grained pinning with a chained variable.
However, the chained variable can be usually replaced by a Planning list variable, which supports pinning up to a defined index in the list.
That way, you can, for example, pin the first three work orders of the technician (firstUnpinnedIndex = 3), letting the solver to change anything starting from the index 4, including adding more work orders.
